# Why I am getting problem with RSA parameters in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "The parameter is incorrect.\r\n",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException",
>       "StackTrace": "   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)\r\n   at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle
>   pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean
>   fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)\r\n   at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[]
>   rgb, Boolean fOAEP)\r\n   at
>   SwiftTele.Areas.Customer.Controllers.AccountsController.Decrypt(String
>   dataToDecrypt, RSAParameters privateKeyInfo) in
>   E:\SwiftTele\SwiftTele\Areas\Customer\Controllers\AccountsController.cs:line
>   456\r\n   at
>   SwiftTele.Areas.Customer.Controllers.AccountsController.PayloadDecryption(String
>   value) in
>   E:\SwiftTele\SwiftTele\Areas\Customer\Controllers\AccountsController.cs:line
>   616\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
>   }

Here is the Code:

```
            var decodeEncEncodeData = Base64Decode(value);
            string urlProtocol = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme.ToLower();

            int rsaProvider = 1;
            CspParameters cspparams = new CspParameters(rsaProvider);
            cspparams.KeyContainerName = "SWIFT_KEYS";
            cspparams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoFlags;
            var RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspparams);
            var fullPath1 = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Certificates/SSL new.crt");
            var puburi = new System.Uri(fullPath1);
            string pubpathuri = puburi.ToString();
            var pubconverted = pubpathuri.Substring(8);
            X509Certificate2 pubcertificate = new X509Certificate2(@pubconverted);
            //RSA = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)pubcertificate.PublicKey.Key;
            //RSA.ToXmlString(false);
            var privateBase64Key = "MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEA2vA9EGCYVUF1lYjIV+plmO1cSYX2dYiVtVX2H7n2+f7Hdp3k" +

                           "TfgLZAjvd7qPpVe8gjNvPH8o7+PyJNdih+LhXY7GVnjTAbyRBOETnGneRH5mFmHC" +
                           "uofiVi1mdHI7eGEMaWlzCrKjtWekWvP94uW/O/OrOyLuTYFLH4EgmFh19TOzmFO9" +
                           "P+OGdxnWo0IjfDhnBuPNVE0x0cVZ4M44igoB/ALA2yAQL072JRT4RvUdJH7ZhF7b" +
                           "w6piIMNA8TdqFVXQk1KG2nv6YRWcWtB1+2ZMD6+xBF55mo2xC++mMYYLxWYVEKqm" +
                           "T0uksjIAfv48QA4AVd0M0NfKi+UoSk8ywJB8mnNMzhiw+1wzM42O6CBFNBPk";

            var RSAparams = new RSAParameters();
            var privateKeyBits = System.Convert.FromBase64String(privateBase64Key);
            using (BinaryReader binr = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(privateKeyBits)))
            {
                byte bt = 0;
                ushort twobytes = 0;
                twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                if (twobytes == 0x8130)
                    binr.ReadByte();
                else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
                    binr.ReadInt16();
                else
                    throw new Exception("Unexpected value read binr.ReadUInt16()");

                twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                if (twobytes != 0x0102)
                    throw new Exception("Unexpected version");

                bt = binr.ReadByte();
                if (bt != 0x00)
                    throw new Exception("Unexpected value read binr.ReadByte()");
                RSAparams.Modulus = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
                RSAparams.Exponent = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
                RSAparams.D = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
                RSAparams.P = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
                RSAparams.Q = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
                RSAparams.DP = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
                RSAparams.DQ = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
                RSAparams.InverseQ = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
            }
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAparams);
            RSA.ToXmlString(true);
            var resultDec = Decrypt(decodeEncEncodeData, RSA.ExportParameters(true));

            var baseDecode = Base64Decode(resultDec);
            //var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultDec);
            dynamic data = JObject.Parse(baseDecode);
            var Customercode = (string)data.SelectToken("CustomerCode");
            var virtualAcc = (string)data.SelectToken("VirtualACCode");
            var payeeName = (string)data.SelectToken("PayeeName");
            var bankInternalTransactionNumber = (string)data.SelectToken("BankInternalTransactionNumber");
            var mode = (string)data.SelectToken("MODE");
            var amt = (string)data.SelectToken("AMT");
            var utr = (string)data.SelectToken("UTR");
            var payeeAccno = (string)data.SelectToken("PayeeAccountNumber");
            var bankPayeeIFSC = (string)data.SelectToken("PayeeBankIFSC");
            var payeePaymentdate = (string)data.SelectToken("PayeePaymentDate");
            var custAccNo = (string)data.SelectToken("CustomerAccountNo");
            bool IsSuccessAcc = false;
            bool IsSuccessName = false;
            EmployeeDAL objEmployeeDAL = new EmployeeDAL();
            EcollectionVo objECollection = new EcollectionVo();
            PaymentsDAL reg = null;
            reg = new PaymentsDAL();

            try
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    IsSuccessAcc = objEmployeeDAL.CheckCustomerAccountNumber(virtualAcc);
                    IsSuccessName = objEmployeeDAL.CheckCustomerName(payeeName, virtualAcc);
                    objECollection = objEmployeeDAL.GetAllTransactionData(bankInternalTransactionNumber);
                    reg.CustomerCode = Customercode;
                    reg.VirtualACCode = virtualAcc;
                    reg.MODE = mode;
                    reg.CustomerAccountNo = custAccNo;
                    reg.AMT = amt;
                    reg.UTR = utr;
                    reg.PayeeName = payeeName;
                    reg.PayeeAccountNumber = payeeAccno;
                    reg.PayeeBankIFSC = bankPayeeIFSC;
                    reg.PayeePaymentDate = payeePaymentdate;
                    reg.BankInternalTransactionNumber = bankInternalTransactionNumber;
                    string FieldMsg = "Fields - / ";
                    bool IsValid = true;
                    string EmptyMsg = "";

                    if (virtualAcc == null || virtualAcc == "" || bankInternalTransactionNumber == null || bankInternalTransactionNumber == "" || custAccNo == null || custAccNo == "" || Customercode == null || Customercode == "" || payeeAccno == null || payeeAccno == "" || bankPayeeIFSC == null || bankPayeeIFSC == "" || payeeName == null || payeeName == "" || mode == null || mode == "" || mode == null || amt == "" || amt == null || payeePaymentdate == "" || utr == null || utr == "")
                    {
                        if (custAccNo == null || custAccNo == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " CustomerAccountNo";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (bankInternalTransactionNumber == null || bankInternalTransactionNumber == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " BankInternalTransactionNumber";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (Customercode == null || Customercode == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + "CustomerCode";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (payeeAccno == null || payeeAccno == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " PayeeAccountNumber";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (bankPayeeIFSC == null || bankPayeeIFSC == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " PayeeBankIFSC";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (payeeName == null || payeeName == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " PayeeName";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (virtualAcc == null || virtualAcc == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " VirtualACCode";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (mode == null || mode == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " MODE";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (payeePaymentdate == null || payeePaymentdate == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " PayeePaymentDate";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (utr == null || utr == "")
                        {
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " UTR";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (amt == null || amt == "")
                        {
                            reg.AMT = "0.00";
                            EmptyMsg = EmptyMsg + " AMT";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                        if (EmptyMsg != "")
                        {
                            reg.SuccessANDRejected = FieldMsg + EmptyMsg + "Should be provided";
                            reg.CODE = "08";
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (payeeAccno.Length < 10)
                    {
                        reg.SuccessANDRejected = "Invalid Payee Account Number Details";
                        reg.CODE = "15";
                        IsValid = false;
                    }
                    else if (virtualAcc.Length < 11)
                    {
                        reg.SuccessANDRejected = "Invalid Virtual Account Number Details";
                        reg.CODE = "16";
                        IsValid = false;
                    }
                    else if (mode != ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["COLLECTION_MODE"].ToString())
                    {
                        reg.SuccessANDRejected = "Invalid Payment Mode.";
                        reg.CODE = "17";
                        IsValid = false;
                    }
                    else if ((payeeAccno != null || payeeAccno != "") && IsSuccessAcc == false)
                    {
                        reg.SuccessANDRejected = "Rejected Transaction/Payee Account Number doesn't exist in database";
                        reg.CODE = "12";
                        IsValid = false;
                    }
                    else if ((custAccNo != null || custAccNo != "") && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CustomerAccountNumber"].ToString() != custAccNo)
                    {
                        reg.SuccessANDRejected = "Invalid Customer Account Number";
                        reg.CODE = "10";
                        IsValid = false;
                    }
                    else if ((payeeName == null || payeeName == "") && IsSuccessName == false)
                    {
                        reg.SuccessANDRejected = "Invalid customer details";
                        reg.CODE = "06";
                        IsValid = false;
                    }
                    else if (objECollection != null && objECollection.TransactionNumber == bankInternalTransactionNumber)
                    {
                        reg.SuccessANDRejected = "Duplicate Transaction{0}: " + objECollection.TransactionNumber + "";
                        reg.CODE = "13";
                        IsValid = false;
                    }
                    if (IsValid == true)
                    {
                        reg.SuccessANDRejected = "Transaction Successful";
                        reg.CODE = "09";
                        IsValid = true;
                    }
                    Savereult = objEmployeeDAL.SaveICICITransaction(reg);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            var encData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reg);
            dynamic data1 = JObject.Parse(encData);
            var data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(encData);
            string payload = Base64Encode(encData);
            //var byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encData);
            var RSAPUB = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            var fullPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Certificates/pub.cer");
            var uri = new System.Uri(fullPath);
            string pathuri = uri.ToString();
            var converted = pathuri.Substring(8);
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@converted);
            RSAPUB = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key;
            resultEnc = Encrypt(payload, RSAPUB.ExportParameters(false));
```

Comment: Which line the code throws exception?

Comment: twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                if (twobytes != 0x0102)
                    throw new Exception("Unexpected version")
where I am trying to get the private key from base64 string using bouncy catlse but getting unexpected version.